# What specialist/engineering/technical vocabulary Nordic-English dictionaries are available?

Tags: dictionary, danish, norwegian, specialist-vocabulary, swedish

I am looking for vocabularies/dictionaries for the Nordic languages specific to engineering. These books do exist for some other fields, such as Danish-English vocabularies for law. I have been unable to find any for technical fields.

I have searched stack exchange with the terms engineering, specialist vocabularies, the tag specialist-vocabolary, technical and a few more, with few results. Search engines present translation companies first, then general dictionaries, and finally a hand full of online translators. Play Books has no listings I recognize as relevant.

Comment: All we can do is google, just like you. For example: Swedish-English & English-Swedish Technical Dictionary (English and Swedish Edition) Paperback
Swedish Edition  by E. Engstrom (Author)

Comment: https://www.abebooks.com/first-edition/Norwegian-English-Technical-Dictionary-Norsk-Engelsk/31072250503/bd Norwegian Maybe you are not googling correctly.

Comment: @Lambie comments are for asking clarifications or suggesting changes to the question. You could post your answers as answers, and then we could vote on them.

Comment: @Tommi Not sure this question is right for this site but even so I wanted to help which is why I did not post an answer.

Comment: The question is okay and an answer would be nice. Mine is not really satisfactory.

Comment: @Tommi Still upvoting it, because it is at least an answer, even if it isn't satisfactory. This is a difficult question to get an answer to, and your answer is at least helping.

Comment: Norwegian - English Technical Dictionary | Norsk - Engelsk Teknisk Ordbok (The Norwegian Council For Technical Terminology | Norsk Rådet for Teknisk Terminologi)
Ansteinsson, John
Published by Published by F. Bruns Bokhandels Forlag Trondheim | George Allen & Unwin Ltd., Ruskin House, 40 Museum Street, London First Edition . 1954., 1954 A suggestion to improve the question. See my link above.

Answer (score 1):

Matematisk ordlista is Norwegians-English. Mathematics, not engineering as such. I have used it to reasonable success. https://matematikkradet.no/ordliste/

Usually I use Wikipedia - find the English term, see if there is an article in the language of interest, and if not, look at similar terms. This typically finds something. Verify in the normal dictionary or similar, or maybe Store norske leksikon for Norwegian terms.

I learned most of the mathematics vocabulary I use by teaching mathematics in Norwegian and by reading a few books, whose substance I knew already or could easily master. Undergraduate textbooks essentially.

Answer (score 0):

The lexicographical part of Wikidata is continuously growing. Nordic languages - Norwegian, Swedish and Danish - and English are relatively well-covered and may contain some specialist and engineering vocabulary. You will be to access the Wikidata lexicographic data through the user interface at https://www.wikidata.org, through the Wikidata API, through the Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org/ or the database dump. My Ordia web application at https://ordia.toolforge.org uses the Wikidata Query service to get an overview of the lexicographic data. A couple of examples are:

- The Danish word "bundventil" - https://ordia.toolforge.org/L204207
- The Danish word "boksplot" - https://ordia.toolforge.org/L1290887

The "ordinary" part of Wikidata may also be able to get you an English-Nordic vocabulary